# replace numeric value instead of boolean

Tags: r

I have a feature called windy and it has boolean values

```
   data<- data.frame(windy=c(FALSE,  TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE))
```

**I need to replace all Falses with 0 and all Trues with 100**

when i use

```
w<-setNames(c(100, 0), c(TRUE, FALSE))[data$Windy]
```

the result is

```
FALSE  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
    0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

How can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
data$windy <- with(data, (windy + 99)*(windy))
data$windy
#[1]   0 100   0   0   0 100
```

---

A more general approach to replace the values with numeric index is

```
 c(0, 100)[(data$windy)+1]
 #[1]   0 100   0   0   0 100
```

Answer (score 3):

```
data$windy2 <- data$windy * 100
data
#   windy windy2
# 1  TRUE    100
# 2  TRUE    100
# 3 FALSE      0
# 4 FALSE      0
# 5  TRUE    100
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you're working with a boolean value already, I would recommend the `ifelse` function.

```
data = data.frame(windy=c(FALSE,  TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,  TRUE))
data$windy = ifelse(data$windy, 100, 0)
data
```